# how to create a call recorder app from call with someone in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, call, record, call-recording

I want to make a program that records sound in flutter, but it is not possible. Is there any solution for this? I want to use it for employees, I just download the apk for them to use, I don't make the apk public (Play Store)!

phone_state_i: ^0.0.3
and other packages, git repositories ...

Comment: So you want an app with UI or just installed it on the phone secretly? Because for both there will be completely different strategies.